# Getting index of unique elements in a vector

Tags: c++

Is there any STL/Boost function in C++ that allows me to find the indices of all unique elements in a vector?

I have seen many solutons to find unique elements, but I need their index.

```
  vector<int> v = { 1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3, 3, ,4,5,5,5,5,5,5 };// already sorted
```

Either I need first index of unique elemnt

```
vector<int> unique_index={0,3,7,9,10};
```

or I need last index of unique elements

```
vector<int> unique_index={2,6,8,9,15};
```

Comment: just loop over vector and keep track of the last seen element. If the current one is not same as last, just insert the current index in the result vector?

Answer (score 5):

A simple way (aside from just keeping track of what the last element was) is to use a [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to test if the current element is unique in the elements of the vector -- seen so far, and populate your unique indexes as you go. This provides a single pass through to collect the indexes where the first unique element is seen, e.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main (void) {
    
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 },
                uniqueidx{};
    std::set<int> s{};
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        if (s.insert(v[i]).second)
            uniqueidx.push_back(i);
    
    for (const auto i : uniqueidx) 
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/set_index_of_unique_in_vector
0
3
7
10
11
```

(**note:** the last two values are `10` and `11`, not `9` and `10` -- you are missing a value in your vector initialization, e.g. `3, ,4`)

If you just wanted a simple-old loop to do the same thing, you could use:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {
    
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 },
                uniqueidx{};
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        if (!i || v[i-1] != v[i])
            uniqueidx.push_back(i);
    
    for (const auto i : uniqueidx) 
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

(same output)

The benefit of the approach with `std::set` is you leave the determination of uniqueness up to `std::set`, with the simple loop -- it's up to you....

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to David's answer of using `std::set`, you could also use `std::map` with its member function `try_emplace(key, value)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main (void) {
    
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    std::map<int, int> m;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        // `i` is only entered if the `m[v[i]]` isn't filled yet.
        m.try_emplace(v[i], i);
    }

    for (auto [valueFromV, indexFromV] : m) 
    {
        std::cout << indexFromV << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change this code and using int instead of a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


std::map<std::string, int> get_unique_indices(const std::vector<std::string>& products) {
    std::vector<std::string> tempProducts(products);
    std::map<std::string, int> result;
    std::sort(std::begin(tempProducts), std::end(tempProducts));
    for (auto it1 = std::begin(tempProducts), it2 = it1; it1 != std::end(tempProducts); it1 = it2) {
        int duplication = 0;
        for (; it2 != std::end(tempProducts) && (*it2 == *it1); ++it2) {
            duplication++;
        }
        if (duplication == 1) {
            result.insert({ *it1, std::find(std::begin(products), std::end(products), *it1) - std::begin(products) });
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> products = { "apple", "orange", "lemon", "apple", "kivi", "orange", "kivi", "melon"};
    auto result = get_unique_indices(products);
    for (const auto& [key, value] : result) {
        std::cout << key << " " << value << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At first, I create another vector to save the original data. (Cause the position of the item will change in the sort method).

then I use two iterators to find duplicate items and count them. the result will be saved in a map instance.
this code must compile with c++17 onwards.